# Gnu Screen and vi - visualization issues

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, aix, scientific-linux, vi

The scenario is as follows:

- gnu screen launched onto a scientific Linux distro
- ssh to an aix machine
- tried to edit a file with vi

And this is what I got:

"ex: 0602-108 screen is not a recognized terminal type.
  [Press return to continue]"

then I am into vi but it displays the file content in a weird fashion, this is an example:

```
    this is row 1
         and this is row 2
             and this is 
    row 3
```

How can this be fixed ?

Comment: `export TERM=xterm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your AIX doesn't know `screen` on your Linux machine, and hence can't figure out the correct terminal control codes (cursor movement et al) to send.

Adjust $TERM before connecting to your AIX box; for example `vt100`, `xterm` or `xterm-color` should get you going, i.e. `export TERM=vt100`. Screen is compatible to those.

There are many more terminal types available; google a bit to find out what is supported by both the machine you're connecting to and your client machine, and what you might need. Usually the above suffice.

Comment: perfect Roman, this is exactly what happened, 
doing the export you suggested and now it's working as a charm! 
thank you very much! 
ps:
`export TERM=xterm` 
is what I did ;)